# Class with different method and object design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am new with design pattern, and I don't know which I have to apply in this case. 
I have some data in a file, so I have to model that data and then start a class with that data.

For the reading of the file and the modeling I choose to apply the Dao pattern, so there is interface (Interface) and his implementation (InterfaceImplementation) that read the file and return the model data (DataModel). 
After I have to instantiate another class (Runner) with that model data e call one of its method.
This is what I have done:

```
public class Factory {
   public void start() {
      Interface dao = new InterfaceImplementation();
      DataModel data = dao.getDataModel();
      Runner runner = new Runner(data);
      runner.run();
   }
}
```

So the client call only the method `new Factory().start()`.

I have some doubts about this solution, I don't think this is a good solution and a good applying of the Factory pattern.

I hope to have been clean, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Factory` class is actually not an implementation of the **[Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)** creational pattern. It is an implementation of the **[Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)** pattern.

Your `Factory` class's purpose is not only to simplify the instantiation process of a `Runner`, but to simplify the entire process of starting a `Runner` which makes it more than a factory.

On a side note, naming things is one of the most important aspect in programming. Choose meaningful names of the [Ubiquitous Language](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UbiquitousLanguage.html) of your domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Factory {
   public void start() {
      Interface dao = new InterfaceImplementation();
      DataModel data = dao.getDataModel();
      Runner runner = new Runner(data);
      runner.run();
   }
}
```

2 remarks :

- A factory creates an object and generally provides a instance of that. Which looks like more to a factory in your code is :

  DataModel data = dao.getDataModel();
- Why re-instantiate `InterfaceImplementation` at each `start()` call  ?

If you have multiple `DataModel`s, a useful factory could by example create/retrieve a specific `DataModel` for clients.

```
public class DataModelFactory {

      private Interface dao = new InterfaceImplementation();

      public DataModel GetDataModelXXX() {
        DataModel dataModel = dao.getDataModelXXX();
        return dataModel ;
      }

      public DataModel GetDataModelYYY() {
        DataModel dataModel = dao.getDataModelYYY();
        return dataModel ;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A factory is intented to ease the creation of an object. In a factory after the creation the object will be returned.

So create the Runner and give it back to the caller.
There you can decide next what to do with it.

Its also important to give the method meaningful names.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that caught my attention: in your current implementation, your client is "kinda" completely decoupled from all other activities. But not in a positive way.

Your client code calls `start()`; and then internally, a lot of things happen. But there is not even a return value from that method.

I am wondering now: how would any of this have an "lasting" effect on your system? Are there some implicit side effects; like that Runner updating some global state singleton somewhere?

In other words: given your code, what would happen if `start()` is called multiple times?! Or ... zero times?!

In that sense, it is not at all clear to me how this code "relates" to anything else. And well, that looks like a problem to me that you should look into.

( and yes, I understand that my input is more of a "code/design review" than a real answer; but heck, maybe it can be helpful )